# Java CountDownLatch wait for async callback

Tags: java, android-asynctask, countdownlatch, socket.io-java-client

First of all, I'm a complete newbie in Java. What I want to achieve is wait for async results before I return them.

**MainActivity.java**:

```
...
     private SendTransport.Listener sendTransportListener = new SendTransport.Listener() {
        @Override
        public String onProduce(JSONObject data) {
            String result = receiveResult(data);
            return result;
        }
    };


    private String receiveResult(JSONObject data) throws InterruptedException {
        String result = "";
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        socket.emit("receive-result", data, new Ack() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                result = args[1];
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        latch.await();
        return result;
    }
...
```

In the code above, the `socket.emit` function never executes. What's wrong with my code? Or better to use some other approach here? If yes, then what?

Comment: are you using `sendTransportListener ` anywhere?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh, of course. If I remove the `CountDownLatch` related code then `socket.emit` executes but I need to get the result from its callback (`new Ack()`) somehow before I proceed.

Comment: seems like you are not getting any result in `call (...)`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh, I do. As I mentioned it works as expected if I remove the `CountDownLatch` bites.

Comment: `latch.countDown();` is being executed before `await()`, debug the flow

Comment: though use interface callbacks